# CSS Modules third party style selector - combining :global and :before

Tags: css-modules

I have a `:before` element applied to my buttons in a `.module.css` file (loaded by vite):

```css
.mybutton:before {
  /* styles */
}
```

```
import { Button as MuiButton, ButtonProps }
import clsx from "clsx";
import styles from "./button.module.css";

export const Button = (props: PropsWithChildren<ButtonProps>) => {
  const { children, className, ...rest } = props;
  return <MuiButton className={clsx(styles.mybutton, className)} {...rest}>{children}</MuiButton>
}
```

When this `.mybutton` class is a member of MUI's [ButtonGroup](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/button-group/), I want to override some of the `.mybutton` styles. The docs say the `.MuiButtonGroup-grouped` class is what I'm looking for.

What is the right way to define a selector for this?

This works, but omits the `.mybutton`:

```css
:global(.MuiButtonGroup-grouped):before { /* snip */ }
```

The following are my failed attempts:

```
:global(.MuiButtonGroup-grouped):before .mybutton
:global(.MuiButtonGroup-grouped) .mybutton:before
:global(.MuiButtonGroup-grouped):before .mybutton:before
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm dumb,

```
.global(.MuiButtonGroup-grouped).mybutton:before
```

Is the correct spelling.